# Is it possible to join "with" query when i use model oriented request

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a query that i'm writed to fetch data

```
with last_sent_at as (
    Select offer_id, lead_id, max(created_at) as sent_at
    From offer_history
    Group by offer_id, lead_id)
```

I need to join it with laravel model system.
So i have three tables: leads => history => offers
I have request
`Lead::with([..., 'offers'])->someFunction(?)->filters()->get();`

And i need to fetch data from 'last_sent_at' but i dont understand how to do it.
Im tried subQuery, but it works wert slow

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by making the **history** table as pivot table so the query would be like this.

```
$query = Lead::with([
             'history' => function($history) {
                $history->select(column names);
            },
            'history.offer' => function ($offer) {
              $offer => select(column names);
            ])->where('Your condition')
                 ->get();
```